# When I try to print the dtype of the indexes of this DataFrame, why does it output |o, and how do I get it to output the dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, sys

if not (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor) >= ((3, 7) or (4, 0)):
    print('You must have atleast Python 3.7 to run this program.')
    sys.exit(input('Press enter to exit:'))
    
Dict = {'First': ['Asher', 'Michael'], 'Last': ['Harris', 'Reeves'], 'Age': [21, 25]}
Dict2 = {'First': ['Jessica', 'Melainie'], 'Last': ['Moores', 'Dinkleton'], 'Age': [35, 27]}

A = pd.DataFrame(Dict) 
B = pd.DataFrame(Dict2)
C = A.describe(include=np.number, percentiles=[.35, .40])
D = B.describe(include=np.number, percentiles=[.35, .40])
E = pd.Series(C['Age'], name='Age(C)', dtype=np.float32)
F = pd.Series(D['Age'], name='Age(D)', dtype=np.float32)
I = pd.DataFrame([E, F])
I.drop(columns='std', inplace=True)
I.columns = I.columns.str.capitalize()

print(I)
print(I.index.dtype.str)#outputs |o instead of 'float32'
```

I made DataFrames of the dictionaries, then used the describe function to extract the numericals from the DataFrames, and turned the output of the describe functions into separate Series, and renamed them to turn them into the indexes of the DataFrame I, and all of the indexed information of the describe functions got turned into the columns of the DataFrame I, with the columns being turned into the indexes.

I tried to print I.index.dtype.str, and I was expecting the output 'float32', but I got |o.

Comment: FYI `>= ((3, 7) or (4, 0))` doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to `>= (3, 7)`

Comment: Why were you expecting "float32"? Please [edit] to clarify, and please make a [mre] so that the problem is more obvious. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: I made both Series in the code equal to float32, so I figured that would carry over to the DataFrame after they became indexes.

Answer (score 0):

That "O" stands for the dtype `"object"`.

If you look at the value of `I.index`: `Index(['Age(C)', 'Age(D)'], dtype='object')`.

The dtype `object` is one of the ways to store text data in Pandas. You can read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html).

Comment: So after converting the 2 Series to the DataFrame the dtype converts from np.float32 to 'object', and in order to convert it back, I would have to write a function that refers to the DataFrame?

Comment: So then what does the pipe stand for?

Comment: Is that just supposed to represent the list?

Comment: What you are printing is the dtype of the index. Each element (columns, index, columns names) have their own dtype. For example, `df.index.dtype` is the dtype of the index. `df['xpto'].dtype` is the dtype of the column "xpto".

Comment: The pipe appears in the `str` attribute of the numpy dtype. I don't know the reason for them to include the pipe. You can run test this: `print(numpy.dtype("object").str)`.